# What is the proper syntax of using broadcast variables in Spark using Scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, broadcast

I want to use a broadcast variable in Spark with Scala. But I can't find enough help on how to use them. Say, I have an object of class A, which I normally would declare as follows in Scala.

```
val a = new A()
```

What would be the syntax of declaring it as a broadcast variable. And how would I call its methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `sc` is a `SparkContext`, then `val broadcasted = sc.broadcast(a)`
will broadcast `a`.
 You can then access it with `broadcasted.value`.

Answer (score 0):

Marth is right. You need also to destroy a broadcast variable by using sc.destroy(blocking) where blocking is a flag. I want to highlight that is recommended to avoid to broadcast small variables.

Comment: Why is it recommended to avoid broadcasting small variables?